# scanf two char[] in function in C and return first one back but it print the second one

Tags: c, function, return

I am a Java programmer and not quite good at C. Today I was trying to scanf two strings and return the first string back to main() function eventually, but the output is the second string.

I know I have another way to complete these codes and I did make it work by using malloc (in comments below). But I just really want to know what's going on here. Could anyone help me look at this mess?

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define len 5
char* shuffle();
char* scanfList();

int main()
{
   printf("hello\n");
   //char *list = malloc(2*len*sizeof(char));
   char * list;
   list = shuffle();
   printf("%s\n",list);
   return 0;
}

char* shuffle() {
   //char *p1 = malloc(len*sizeof(char));
   //char *p2 = malloc(len*sizeof(char));
   static char * p1, * p2;
   p1 = scanfList();
   p2 = scanfList();
   printf("shuffle%s\n",p1);
   printf("shuffle%s\n",p2);
   return p1;
}

char* scanfList() {
    printf("Please input a list:\n");
    //char *list = malloc(len*sizeof(char));
    static char list[len];
    scanf("%s",list);
    return list;
}
```

**Output**

```
HHH$ ./a.out
hello
Please input a list:
123
Please input a list:
456
shuffle456
shuffle456
456
```

Comment: Your second `scanfList()` call will overwrite the `list` array and both `p1` and `p2` points to that. They are aliases of each other. So thats why the same output.

Comment: That's what I guess. But is that means functions in C will not create a new array for the list but reuse it?

Comment: variables lifetimes which declared in functions ends when the function returns. although `static` variable in function will retain their values, but its address will be the same, and you returning that.

Comment: But if I don't use static, the value cannot even pass back to the call function. So is the only way is using malloc in ``scanfList()``?

Comment: Kind of yes, since you need a real copy, but currently it is just a shallow copy. So yes you allocate memory on the heap with malloc and then copy the string with `strcpy` for example to this allocated space and returning the pointer which points to this allocated memory. Or you make a string array like `char str[2][20]` and passing a pointer to this. And writing the result in it.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",list);`   1)  to avoid a buffer overflow (and the resulting undefined behavior)  us a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.   1 less than the length of the input buffer because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input.  2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (the `scanf` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers.  I.E.   if( scanf("%4s",list) != 1) { handle error }`

Answer (score 0):

suggest declaring the arrays in the `main()` function and passing a pointer to the sub function(s), similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 256

void shuffle( char *, char * );
void scanfList( char * );

int main( void )
{
   char p1[ LEN ];
   char p2[ LEN ];
   printf( "hello\n" ); 
   shuffle( p1, p2 );
   printf( "%s--%s\n", p1, p2 );
   return 0;
}

void shuffle( char *list1, char *list2 )
{

   scanfList( list1 );
   scanfList( list2 );
   printf( "shuffle %s\n", list1 );
   printf( "shuffle %s\n", list2 );
}

void scanfList( char *list ) 
{
    printf( "Please input a list:\n" );
    if( scanf( "%255s", list ) != 1 )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", "scanf for input failed, exiting\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

here is a typical run of the above code:

```
hello
Please input a list:
abc
Please input a list:
def
shuffle abc
shuffle def
abc--def
```